# I am trying to Execute the Performance Test in ALM 12.55 but I am seeing the below error:

Tags: performance, loadrunner, alm, vugen

[image]
[image]

Tried rebooting all the servers where ALM is installed.
Re-run the Server Configuration Wizard.
I have attached all the screenshots for the reference.
Please go through the screenshot and provide any possible help here.

Comment: error message suggest that you should have `<customErrors` tag in your `web.config` file with mode attribute set to off:```<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: which may allow you to see the details of the error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like this application error from Twitter today related to people trying to purchase Taylor Swift Eras movie tickets in the Philippines?

Your hypothesis is that this is a tool error.  Mine is that it is an application under test error.

[image: Taylor Swift Concert Movie Concert ticket purchase failure]